# Supersede a Javascript redirect with a redirect elsewhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I have a popover that appears on a page after a user clicks a link.  When the user then clicks the button in the popover, it does some Javascript that I need to still happen, and then redirects the user to another page.  I'm trying to interrupt that redirect, and have the user go to a separate page, but nothing I'm trying seems to work.

If I do the redirect right away, it works, but the rest of the Javascript I need to run doesn't get executed.  The same with preventDefault, that seems to prevent the other Javascript from happening that I need to still happen.  I also tried using:

```
$(".specialImg").click(function () {
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        window.location.href = "https://example.com";
    };
});
```

But the original redirect still happens.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can accomplish this?  I have Javascript and jQuery at my disposal.  I should mention I'm trying to do this through Optimizely, so I can't edit the code that's executing directly.

Comment: `preventDefault` just prevents the normal action of user interface elements, it has no effect on Javascript actions.

Comment: `beforeunload` isn't allowed to do a redirect. All it can do is return a string, which may be shown in the "Do you really want to leave the page?" prompt.

Answer (score 2):

You can execute the code you want and in the end redirect to the other page :

```
$(".specialImg").click(function () {
    //Do here what you want

    //Then in the end redirect to new page
    window.location = "https://example.com";
});
```

Hope this helps.